# When I skip a review what happens?

Tags: support, status-completed, review-queues, help-center

A little while ago I skipped a 'Late Answer' review because I just wasn't sure either way whether it was a good answer or not.

It sounds so simple but I am presuming that if I skip the review item it just stays in the queue for the next reviewer who comes along to take a look?

The help centre page [Access review queues](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) says when and why to skip, but not what happens next to that item?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Skip option skips that review *for you* and will not place it in your queue again.  It's not counted as a review in your stats, and is as if you never saw the review.  Another reviewer will see that review in their queue.

From [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) (emphasis added)

> Any time you are unsure of whether a post should be closed or
>   reopened, you can and should Skip it to **allow another user to review
>   it**.

Also note that unless your privileges allow a super-vote, your review alone won't decide what to do with the reviewed post.  Posts are reviewed by multiple users in the queue, and it takes multiple votes the same way for a vote to be closed or opened.  Depending on your privileges, if you edit a post in a queue that edit may also then be reviewed.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so. I have just spent over hour or so reading on both this Meta, and Meta SE, and didn't come across the post that you have linked to. I shall have a good read. It started because I searched for the post after I skipped it, and I found it, unchanged. So it got me thinking had I done the right thing, I guess the next reviewer thought that it was good.

Comment: @MartinHügi the post may still have been in the queue after you searched it again.  Being in the queue doesn't mean it's unavailable on the site, it just means it need to be looked at by our community of users.  A later reviewer may indeed still opt to change, close, delete the post if it's still in the queue.

Comment: @MartinHügi Also, I often use Google to find posts, especially on Meta SE

Comment: That's a good top tip, thanks